# Htaccess redirect subdomains to a specific page without changing the link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a php script on which i will generate links with random subdomains.For example : x.domain.com sius.domain.com x5-.domain.com and so on. In fact these subdomains doesn't really exist what i want is that when user goes to any link (RANDOM).domain.com it shows the content of domain.com/result.php?rand=(RANDOM).
PS:I considered (RANDOM) as the variable. and i want to exclude www.
I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/result.php  [L,R]
```

But nothing seems to work. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /result.php?rand=%1  [L,QSA]
```

You can't redirect (`http://...` and `[R]`) without link change. With this code you rewrite without redirection.